# Как записать текст в буфер обмена с помощью LUA?

Tags: lua

Каким образом я могу сделать это?

Answer (score 1):

Скачайте winapi.dll и используйте документацию:
http://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/api.html

```
local W = require 'winapi'
W.set_clipboard ("Send text to clipboard.")
```

скачать dll можно по ссылке: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/A8PS/Y2rfJ26LC